# NSNotication at time of day

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimer, nsnotificationcenter

I need my application to run method at a certain time of day, I think the best way would be to set up a notification for when it would get that time. I have used NSNoticationCenter before but I'm not sure how to set it up for a time of day.

Edit:
I am going at it a different way using NSTimer. Here is my code

```
    NSCalendar* myCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [myCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit
                                             fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[components setHour: 10];
[components setMinute: 5];
[components setSecond: 0];
NSDate *date = [myCalendar dateFromComponents:components];

NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:date
                                      interval:0.0
                                        target:self
                                      selector:@selector(fired:)
                                      userInfo:nil
                                       repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-CJBJCBDE) class methods. Create timer object and set fire date accordingly. In the timer callback method implement method to post the required notification.

Alternative way is using [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:). In the selector method post required notification.

Comment: With NSTimer can I put the time of day when to fire off?

Comment: You can use initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats  init method. This takes NSDate argument wherein you specify at what time of day you want to fire the timer. 'setFireDate:' method can be used to alter the timer fireDate later stage.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, how do I tell it what time of day to fire?

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Thanks